# Screeching during washing machine spin

Tags: washing-machine

I recently replaced the gearbox on my Whirlpool washing machine, a wtw5000dw1 due to some other obnoxious noises. The part number is W11035751 for reference.

[Image of gearbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAOCT.jpg)

There is play on the inner axel, maybe 1/8 of an inch moving through (not side to side). It's enough for the splutch assembly to not quite disengage which I believe is the cause of the sound.

Is the play usual? A manufacturing defect, a problem I caused installing?

Comment: No, sounds like a duff bearing or a misplaced one.

Comment: Look for something that's rubbing that isn't supposed to be...Maybe a misplaced/misadjusted/missing guide wheel/roller? Maybe try greasing up the bearings? As usual, hard to tell without pictures, etc.